# Attempt to present <vc> on <vc> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift

I am attempting to fetch lat long coordinates from a postcode/zipcode using google api:

```
func getLatLngForZip(zipCode: String, completion: CLLocationCoordinate2D -> ())  {

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(baseUrl)address=\(zipCode)&key=\(apikey)")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        data, response, error -> Void in

        var locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everything is fine, GoogleAPI downloaded successfully.")

            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                if let result = json["results"] as? NSArray, let status = json["status"] as? String {

                    if status == "OK" {
                        if let geometry = result[0]["geometry"] as? NSDictionary {
                            if let location = geometry["location"] as? NSDictionary {
                                let latitude = location["lat"] as! Double
                                let longitude = location["lng"] as! Double
                                print("\n\(latitude), \(longitude)")
                                locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                            }
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            completion(locationCoordinates)
                        }
                    } else {
                        let vc = PostCodeController()
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Error with GoogleAPI: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

simply, if the status from the json is "OK", then the postcode/zipcode entered is correct and the lat long can be fetched.  Otherwise, the postcode is invalid for one reason or another and I want to display an alert telling the user that the postcode entered is invalid.

I understand that the code inside the else clause should not be there.  I feel like I should be calling the alert from inside `PostCodeController()`, not where it is now.

This is how its called from in `PostCodeController()`

```
func tappedFindSalonButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.postCode = self.finderView.textField.text!
    fetchGoogleAPI()
}

func fetchGoogleAPI() {
    GoogleAPI().getLatLngForZip(finderView.textField.text!) {
        location in
        self.presentListControllerWithLocation(location)
    }
}
func presentListControllerWithLocation(locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let listController = ListController()
    listController.currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: locationCoordinate.longitude)
    listController.postCode = postCode
    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: listController)
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Why am I getting in this situation 'Attempt to present "" on "" whose view is not in the window hierarchy'? I've come across it before but haven't fully grasped the meaning of it.

How can I change my code to display an alert when the postcode entered is invalid?

Comment: what is "presentListControllerWithLocation" ?

Comment: You cannot initialize a view controller in the view hierarchy with the default initializer `PostCodeController()`. You need the actual reference to the controller instance in the storyboard.

Comment: @UmairAfzal edited. I'm not using a storyboard

Comment: If you don't use storyboard you have to call the designated initializer `init(nibName:bundle:)` to load the view controller from a nib file